# QGIS SLD export from QOSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geoserver, qgis, sld

I was able to get this map https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=10/40.6983/-73.9792  on my QGIS with the QOSM plugin.

When I'm using a layer built from some .osm data, I can just save the style as SLD and use it in Geoserver.

I'm having a problem with QOSM ; I can't figure out how to save the map from the above website to a SLD which will be used in Geoserver (even though it gets openned in QGIS and it is fully zoomable there).

How can I do that ?

Also anytime I try to copy/add the style of this layer I get the following error

```
NotImplementedError: QgsPluginLayer.writeSymbology() is abstract and must be overridden
```

Comment: Looks like you need to implement the method

Comment: @iant Yeah. The problem is that the plugin is calling the method. So it's kinda asking me to program the plugin... I don't think I have what it takes to do that